# How to share async method across the components - LitElement

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I was trying to build a couple of components using **`lit-element`** where i have used async method which will be used to **`fetch`** the same data from an API.

**Utility method:**

```
async resolveData() {
    let response = await fetch('./emp-data.json');
    let empData = await response.json();
    let employees = null;

    employees = empData.employees;

    return employees;
}
```

**Question:** How can i actually separate this utility method from the components and just re-use it. Is there a best way to fix this in the context of **`lit-element`**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a separate services in order to serve a particular service across. Here is how:

**step 1:** create a service file `services.js`

```js
export const litServices = (() => {
    const services = {}
    services.apiService1 = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('./emp-data.json').catch(err => {
            return {
                data: {
                    isError: true
                }
            }
        })
        return response.data;
    }
    return services;
})();
```

**step 2:** Import services into your component and call when needed

```js
import {
    html,
    LitElement
} from 'litElements'
import {
    litServices
} from 'services'

class comp extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {

        }
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.receivedData = this._resolveData();
        this._formatResponse(this.receivedData)
    }
    async _resolveData() {
        const response = await litServices.apiService1();
        return response;
    }
    _formatResponse(receivedData) {
        console.log('First API response is: ', firstApiResponse);
    }
}
```

This will call the service when needed. This service can be reused across [How to create services in  litElement - sabarinath blog](https://jsabarinath.wordpress.com/2020/07/10/how-to-use-services-in-lit-element/)